# Tapestry use Java expression into <t:if> component

Tags: java, if-statement, expression, tapestry

I'm a beginner in tapestry and I was wondering If it is possible to use a java expression as test into an  component

I've been trying this way but it's not working

```
<t:loop source="pathologies" value="valueFromCda">
  <t:if test="valueFromCda instanceof String">
```

the error is the following one :

```
Could not convert 'valueFromCda instanceof StrucDocList' into a component parameter binding: Error parsing property expression 'valueFromCda instanceof StrucDocList': line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'valueFromCda'
```

valueFromCda and pathologies are properties in my controller:

```
@Property
private Object valueFromCda;

@Property
private List<Object> pathologies;
```

Thank you for your answers ! have a good afternoon ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "test" parameter expects a [property-binding](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-parameters.html#ComponentParameters-Property%3aBindings) by default. Tapestry will look for a property "valueFromCda instanceof String" or a POJO-like getter ("isXXX" for boolean return types is also ok) "getValueFromCda instanceof String", which it can’t find because there’s no such property or method in your page/component.

Instead you should write one like this:

**tml**

```
<t:if test="valueInstanceOfString">
```

**component**

```
public boolean isValueInstanceOfString() {
    return valueFromCda instanceof String;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Actually I did what you said but I just wanted to be sure there was no other way to do it. 
It's a bit weird to declare a method for such a simple test, I thought maybe it was possible to do it more easily.

Comment: Templates are for presentation, not logic. With tapestry's live class reloading, it's easy to put your logic in component classes instead. By forcing this, your templates remain clean. JSP on the other hand allows this. IMHO JSP pages can get very messy because this type of logic is allowed. Another benefit is that logic is easy to unit test of its in the component class.